# Microsoft Access memo field truncated on query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've accessed this same memo field in the past and used the notes found [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html) to avoid truncating this field. For some reason my new query is starting to truncate the `Description` field and I'm not able to find what is causing the truncation.

```
SELECT TableA.ID, Min(IIf([TableA].[YFLAG]="Y",[TableB].[CRHR],[TableA].[CRHR])) 
    AS [Min Credit], First(TableC.COU_DESC) AS Description
FROM (TableA LEFT JOIN TableC ON (TableA.END_DATE = TableC.END_DATE) AND 
    (TableA.ID = TableC.ID)) LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
GROUP BY TableA.ID
HAVING (((Min(IIf([TableA].[YFLAG]="Y",[TableB].[CRHR],[TableA].[CRHR])))>0));
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the `Having` statement, but not sure how to fix.

Comment: Could you give a smaller sample of the query that still replicates the problem?

Comment: I don't see the union that was used as an example in your links.

Comment: I simplified the code and narrowed down the problem to the `Having` statement.

Comment: I have not managed to reproduce the truncation using your query above with a mock-up.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if using a union like this will work

```
SELECT TableA.ID,0 AS [Min Credit],TableC.COU_DESC AS Description WHERE (FALSE)
Union All
SELECT TableA.ID, Min(IIf([TableA].[YFLAG]="Y",[TableB].[CRHR],[TableA].[CRHR])) 
    AS [Min Credit], First(TableC.COU_DESC) AS Description
FROM (TableA LEFT JOIN TableC ON (TableA.END_DATE = TableC.END_DATE) AND 
    (TableA.ID = TableC.ID)) LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.ID
GROUP BY TableA.ID
HAVING (((Min(IIf([TableA].[YFLAG]="Y",[TableB].[CRHR],[TableA].[CRHR])))>0));
```

This "union all" tricks Access into keeping the whole memo field according to the link you shared.